# when i build a code this shows annot open source file "cryptopp/sha.h" and cannot open source file "crypto++/sha256.h"

Tags: c++

The code includes the following functionalities:

- Calculation of the SHA-256 checksum of a file using Crypto++ library
- Checking if the checksum of a file has changed since the last check
- Displaying a message box if the file has been modified
- Exporting a function to be used in the DLL
- Initializing the previous checksum value at the beginning of the DLL

The error messages reported by the user indicate that the program is unable to locate the header file "cryptopp/sha.h" and the identifier "sha256".

Comment: It looks like you failed or forgot to specify correct include directries, or to install required libraries.

Comment: how are you building this code? Have you installed the crypto++ library?